# tensorflow dataset from generator slow

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I have a data file, the format like:
A  B C x,y,z

because A B C is very very big, so I don't want to convert it to below format into disk

1. A B C x
2. A B C y
3. A B C z

now I am using dataset.from_generator to read it, but it is very slow when training.

how could I solve this?

the logis is:

```
def gen_sample2(self):
    for file_name in self.file_names:

        with open(file_name) as f:
            for line in f:
                item = line.strip().split(',')
                pids_str = item[4]
                pids = [int(pid) for pid in pids_str.split('|') if pid in self.pid_set]
                for item_id in pids:
                    yield {"gender": item[1], "topics": item[2], "weights": item[3], "item_id": item_id}

def get_dataset_iterator(self):
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(self.gen_sample2,
                                             output_types={"gender":tf.string,
                                                           "topics":tf.string,
                                                           "weights":tf.string,
                                                           "item_id":tf.int32
                                                           })
    dataset = dataset.batch(self.batch_size)

    # if self.buffer_size > 0:
    #     dataset = dataset.shuffle(self.buffer_size)

    dataset = dataset.repeat(self.iter)
    return  dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
```

Comment: You should convert your data to [TFRecords format](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/tf_records), that way TensorFlow will be able to read it much faster.

Comment: that will be huge, say A is a very long string

Comment: I mean just the source comma-separated file. Couldn't you convert that into a TFRecords file? It should be a comparable size (then you would do a similar transformations to what you do now).